# Does a neural network need to be retrained on both old and new data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am new to neural networks and wondered if it is possible to improve an existing model without retraining over a pervious data set.

For example, say I have a neural network that has been trained on a set of data and outputs $\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{d}_1$

Next, I have received new data set $\mathbf{X}_2,\mathbf{d}_2$.

Do I have to retrain my neural algorithm on both $\mathbf{X}_2,\mathbf{d}_2$ and $\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{d}_1$ or is there a way to simplify the process and run only on $\mathbf{X}_2,\mathbf{d}_2$?

From the way I understood the basic algorithm, it does not seem to be the case.

On top of the answer proposed by @noe:
I have come across a Wikipedia article discussing this topic under the name "continual learning":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning

Answer (score 1):

There are research lines that study neural network "lifelong learning" or "continual learning", which precisely involves incremental learning from new information. However, they are not often used in practice.

A usual technique is to evaluate how much the new data deviates from the old data (i.e. concept drift) and only retrain if they differ too much. This maintains the model current while saving retrainings.